# If $ f(x)=(x^2-1)^n $ then $ f^{(n)} $ has $ n $ roots

Tags: calculus

Let $ n \in \mathbb{N} $ and $ f(x) = (x^2-1)^n $. I want to prove that the equation $ f^{(n)}(x)=0 $ has exactly $ n $ roots, all in $ (-1, 1) $.

Comment: Is the $n$ in $f^{(n)}$ the same as the $n$ in $(x^2-1)^n$?

Comment: I think this question is related to the roots of the Legendre Polynomials(in which all roots are in the interval $(-1,1)$. I don't know how to prove it though. Look it up!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hint: The function $f(x)$ has $-1$ and $1$ as roots with multiplicity $n$. Then $f'(x)$ has these roots with multiplicity $n-1$ and one new root strictly between them. Just continue this process $n$ times.